how to change registry in VBS
I want to change registry UserPreferencesMask value.
When I run my code, I don't get the results I want.
I want set value like below image
enter image description here
if i input command in cmd like
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v UserPreferencesMask /t REG_BINARY /d "9012018010000000" /f 

command can change registry value.
But VBScript it's really hard to change...
Dim WSHShell, value, regPath

regPath = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\UserPreferencesMask" 

Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WSHShell.RegWrite regPath, 901201801, "REG_BINARY" 

value = WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\UserPreferencesMask")
MsgBox(value)


in my source code is there something missing? or change?
Thank you!
result is not correct also i think regwrite second value is decimal

Note that you also have the option of running the reg.exe command from your VBS script.
